# "'charmap' codec can't encode character" (Http Request)

Tags: python, encoding, request

I am using `urllib.request.urlopen` to get a *.srt file from a web API. The (relevant) code (Python 3.x):

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    result = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    print(result)

    with open(subpath, 'w') as file:

        file.write(result)
        file.close()
```

This works fine, with the exception of some files. With certain files I receive the following error:
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u266a' in position 37983: character maps to <undefined>`

(\u266a is the quarter-note symbol.)

How to solve this? Could I filter this character from the bytes object returned by .read()? Or can I have encode errors be ignored? Thanks in advance.

Also, please note I did find numerous topics concerning '...can't encode character...'-errors, however, in most cases using .decode('utf-8') was the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to solve the decoding error, however, I found a way around it.

By writing to the file in binary mode the bytes object can be written, so no decoding is necessary:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    result = response.read()
    # print(result)

    with open(subpath, 'wb') as file:

        file.write(result)
        file.close()
```